# is it possible to use 2 apis for one input. one api to populate the data and the other one to update the data in the first api

Tags: reactjs, next.js13

I've a question.

I've a form component and when the component get's render there's a request that happen to the backend and a big object comes back from the backend in order to populate the form fields in the frontend

here's an input field for my example.

```
<TextField
 error={errors.firstName}
 placeholder="First name"
 required
 fullWidth
 disabled={hasFinanceApplication}
 value={firstName}
 onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
 datatestid="first-name"
/>
```

The input have it's own state where it save the data that comes from the backend.

now, the backend want to create a small apis in order to be used to update the inputs and the big object that comes in the first place.

so, is it possible to use to api's. one to populate the input field and the other one to update the input and the other api. I don't believe that quite possible. just wanted to make sure.

Comment: I dont see any reason why this would be difficult. What issues are you thinking you’ll encounter?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev The issues is - in this case I will have 2 states - first one will be used to populate the input - the second one should be added to the input to update the input itself - so, how would I use 2 states with the input value?

Comment: let's imagine that I have a state which is `firstName` this state is used to populate the data in the input field from the first object - now, I should have a new state `newFirstName` to be used in order to be added to the second object that will be sent to the backend to update the first object.

Comment: So, do you think it makes sense to use 2 states with one input?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev i think I missed a point to make this work - through save the populated state in a new state and use the new state within my input and the api to update the first api that is going to populate my form fields. Thank you :)

Comment: You can write any logic you want for the onChange handler.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev totally agree and much appreciated